# Move edges closer to origin

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

Basic example I've got a cylinder and I want to move half the edges closer to the centre of the cylinder. I thought selecting every second edge and scaling constraining X & Y (Not Z) axis only would work. But it doesn't seem to have any visible effect.

I am using 2.8 if it makes any difference.

Comment: Make a note of your Pivot center, and include it in your question.. also look out for the 'Manipulate Center Points Only' setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Blender 2.80 (Beta) it works still the same as in Blender 2.7x

With the edges selected, hit <kbd>S</kbd>, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to scale the vertices along the X and Y axis.

[image: scaling x+y]

Comment: Thats what I did. It didn't work. I tried changing the scaling mode too but no avail. Okay its not working in that particular file. I must have changed some option somewhere.

Comment: Yet it is still working for me. Hit S, **then Shift+Z at the same time**.

Comment: Okay in a brand new blend file. It works for me. In the existing file it doesn't

Comment: The reason it wasn't working is that I had my piviot point set wrong.